# nonlinear fourth-order differential equation type

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does anybody know how to reduce such nonlinear fourth-order differential equation to well-known type (like Ricatti, Painlevé, sine-Gordon etc)?

$\frac{{{d^4}\phi }}{{d{x^4}}} + q\frac{{{d^2}\phi }}{{d{x^2}}} - {\omega ^2}\sin\phi  = 0$

Comment: I doubt you can reduce order here. I would just solve numerically

Comment: Please, be aware that “ricatti” in Italian means (more or less) “blackmail”; the mathematician was *Riccati*.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{{{d^4}\phi }}{{d{x^4}}} + q\frac{{{d^2}\phi }}{{d{x^2}}} - {\omega ^2}\sin\phi  = 0$$

Even in simplified case of $q=0$, the equation $\quad\frac{{{d^4}\phi }}{{d{x^4}}} - {\omega ^2}\sin\phi  = 0\quad$ as no closed form solution, as far as I know.

The solutions of the second order ODE : $\quad\frac{{{d^2}\phi }}{{d{x^2}}} - {\omega ^2}\sin\phi  = 0\quad$ involve the $am$ Jacobi elliptic function : $\quad \phi=-2\,am\bigg(\frac12(x+c_2)\sqrt{c_1-2\omega^2}\:\bigg|\:\frac{4\omega^2}{2\omega^2+c_1} \bigg)$

As far as I know, no special function was defined for solving similar ODE of higher order such as $\quad\frac{{{d^3}\phi }}{{d{x^3}}} - {\omega ^2}\sin\phi  = 0\quad$ and even more $\quad\frac{{{d^4}\phi }}{{d{x^4}}} - {\omega ^2}\sin\phi  = 0\quad$ and a-fortiori for your equation $\quad\frac{{{d^4}\phi }}{{d{x^4}}} + q\frac{{{d^2}\phi }}{{d{x^2}}} - {\omega ^2}\sin\phi  = 0$.

As usualy done, one can consider the approximate case of small $\phi\quad\to\quad \sin(\phi)\simeq \phi$ so that :
$$\frac{{{d^4}\phi }}{{d{x^4}}} + q\frac{{{d^2}\phi }}{{d{x^2}}} - {\omega ^2}\phi  \simeq 0$$
$$\phi(x)\simeq c_1e^{r_1x}+c_2e^{r_2x}+c_3e^{r_3x}+c_4e^{r_4x}\qquad r_{1,2,3,4}=\pm\sqrt{\frac12\left(-q\pm\sqrt{q^2+4\omega^2}\right)}$$
Of course, some of the $r$ are complex which implies sinusoidal terms is the solution.

Better approximate could be obtained with more or less limited series, but it should be arduous calculus. In practice, for accurate numerical result, it is simpler to directly solve the ODE thanks to numerical method.

Comment: A lot of thanks for your answer . I did all these approximations as well as got the solution of sine-Gordon equation in the form of Jacobi elliptic functions. I just try to know how does classify this type equation among well-known differential equations? Anyway thank you again.

Comment: I don't know if this fourth degree non-linear ODE has a particular name. In term of classification, it belongs to the ODEs of autonomous kind. The change of function $\frac{d\phi}{dx}=F(\phi)$ reduces to order three. But the reduction of order is not an advantage because the three order ODE is still non-linear and with more complicated terms.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\dfrac{d^4\phi}{dx^4}+q\dfrac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}-\omega^2\sin\phi=0$

$\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\dfrac{d^4\phi}{dx^4}+q\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\dfrac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}-\omega^2(\sin\phi)\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}=0$

$\int\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\dfrac{d^4\phi}{dx^4}~dx+q\int\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\dfrac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}~dx-\omega^2\int(\sin\phi)\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}~dx=0$

$\int\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}~d\left(\dfrac{d^3\phi}{dx^3}\right)+q\int\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}~d\left(\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\right)-\omega^2\int\sin\phi~d\phi=0$

$\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\dfrac{d^3\phi}{dx^3}-\int\dfrac{d^3\phi}{dx^3}~d\left(\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\right)+q\int\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}~d\left(\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\right)-\omega^2\int\sin\phi~d\phi=0$

$\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\dfrac{d^3\phi}{dx^3}-\int\dfrac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}\dfrac{d^3\phi}{dx^3}~dx+q\int\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}~d\left(\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\right)-\omega^2\int\sin\phi~d\phi=0$

$\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\dfrac{d^3\phi}{dx^3}-\int\dfrac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}~d\left(\dfrac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}\right)+q\int\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}~d\left(\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\right)-\omega^2\int\sin\phi~d\phi=0$

$\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\dfrac{d^3\phi}{dx^3}-\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}\right)^2+\dfrac{q}{2}\left(\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\right)^2+\omega^2\cos\phi=c$

$2\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\dfrac{d^3\phi}{dx^3}-\left(\dfrac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}\right)^2+q\left(\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\right)^2+\omega^2\cos\phi=C_1$